# cassandra node discovery

Tags: cassandra

I just set up a 3 node system with ip addresses "192.168.0.101", "192.168.0.102", "192.168.0.103". I have set the seeds value on the configuration of all three machines as 
`seeds: "192.168.0.101,192.168.0.102,192.168.0.103"`

However, on running nodetool on any of them, only the `103` machine gets discovered.

> node101:/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-0.8.5/bin# ./nodetool
>   ring -h 192.168.0.101 Address         DC          Rack        Status
>   State   Load            Owns    Token
>
> 192.168.0.103   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  151.96 KB
>   100.00% 38174485210079977599903748344879358256

Could someone tell me where the problem lies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend

1. Make sure you're on the latest stable release of Cassandra
2. Start with a single node as seed on all machines (say, .101)
3. Add this to log4j-server.properties:

   log4j.logger.org.apache.cassandra.gms=TRACE