# Is it ok to set all cassandra nodes as seeds?

Tags: cassandra

I'm interested in speeding up the process of bootstrapping a cluster and adding/removing nodes (Granted, in the case of node removal, most time will be spend draining the node). I saw in the source code that nodes that are seeds are not bootstrapped, and hence do not sleep for 30 seconds while waiting for gossip to stabilize. Thus, if all nodes are declared to be seeds, the process of creating a cluster will run 30 seconds faster. My question is is this ok? and what are the downsides of this? Is there a hidden requirement in cassandra that we have at least one non-seed node to perform a bootstrap (as suggested in the answer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389531/cassandra-node-discovery))? I know I can shorten `RING_DELAY` by modifying `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`, but if simply setting all nodes to be seeds would be better or faster in some way, that might be better. (Intuitively, there must be a downside to setting all nodes to be seeds since it appears to strictly improve startup time.)

Answer (score 4):

Good question. Making all nodes seeds is not recommended. You want new nodes and nodes that come up after going down to automatically migrate the right data. Bootstrapping does that. When initializing a fresh cluster without data, turn off bootstrapping. For data consistency, bootstrapping needs to be on at other times. A new start-up option -Dcassandra.auto_bootstrap=false was added to Cassandra 2.1: You start Cassandra with the option to put auto_bootstrap=false into effect temporarily until the node goes down. When the node comes back up the default auto_bootstrap=true is back in effect. Folks are less likely to go on indefinitely without bootstrapping after creating a cluster--no need to go back and forth configuring the yaml on each node.

In multiple data-center clusters, the seed list should include at least one node from each data center. To prevent partitions in gossip communications, use the same list of seed nodes in all nodes in a cluster. This is critical the first time a node starts up.

These recommendations are mentioned on several different pages of 2.1 Cassandra docs: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/gettingStartedCassandraIntro.html.